# Recursive search return all keys where value is present

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Currently stuck trying to get the last part working, wanting to get all array keys returned where the value exists.

**Test data**

```
$testArr = array(
    'id' => '249653315914',
    'title' => 'testing',
    'description' => 'testing',
    'usernames' => array('jake', 'liam', 'john'),
    'masterNames' => array('jake'),
    'data' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'jake'
        )
    )
);
```

**Method**

```
recursive_search('jake', $testArr);

function recursive_search($needle, $haystack, $child = false) {
    $values = array();
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        $current_key = $key;
        if($needle === $value OR (is_array($value) && $children = recursive_search($needle, $value, true) !== false)) {
            if($child) {
                if($needle == $value) {
                    return true;
                }
                echo "children: $child, current_key: $current_key   ";
                return $current_key;
            }
            echo "current_key: $current_key, key: $key <br>";
            $values[] = $current_key;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($values)) {
        return $values;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Output**

```
current_key: usernames, key: usernames 
current_key: masterNames, key: masterNames 
children: 1, current_key: aliases current_key: data, key: data 
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'usernames' (length=5)
  1 => string 'masterNames' (length=8)
  2 => string 'data' (length=4)
```

**Expected**

```
  array(
    'usernames',
    'masterNames',
    'data' => array('aliases')
  )
```

I'm losing track on the `$child` part I think, somewhere I should be returning something and assigning it but I think I've looked at this to long and overlooking the obvious.

Any help is awesome.

Comment: `Expected` you can not combine regular array with associative array. I meant the output that you presented. `'usernames'` is either a value and it will be `[0] => 'usernames'` or it is a key and it will be `'usernames' => something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$testArr = array(
    'id' => '249653315914',
    'title' => 'jake',
    'description' => 'testing',
    'usernames' => array('jake', 'liam', 'john'),
    'masterNames' => array('jake'),
    'data' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'jake'
        ),
        'aliases2' => array('level3' => array('jake'))
    )
);

function recursive_search($needle, $haystack) {
   $return = array();
   if (is_array($haystack))
      foreach($haystack as $key => $value)
      {
          if (is_array($value))
          {
             $child = recursive_search($needle, $value); 
             if (is_array($child) && !empty($child))
                $return = array_merge($return, array($key => $child));
             elseif ($child) $return[] = $key;
          }
          elseif ($value === $needle)
             if (is_integer($key))
                return true;
             else
                $return[] = $key;
      }
      elseif ($haystack === $needle)
         return true;

   return $return;
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => title
    [1] => usernames
    [2] => masterNames
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => aliases
            [aliases2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => level3
                )

        )

)
```

Testing is needed, no warranty that it will work in all cases. Also, in the cases like this `array('level3' => array('jake'), 'jake')`, it will not go deeper to level3 and so on, as 'jake' is present in the original array. Please mention if that is not a desired behavior.

**Edit by Bankzilla: To work with objects**

```
function recursive_search($needle, $haystack) {
    $return = array();
    if (is_array($haystack) || is_object($haystack)) {
        foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $child = recursive_search($needle, $value); 
                if ((is_array($child) || is_object($child)) && !empty($child)) {
                    $return = array_merge($return, array($key => $child));
                } elseif ($child) {
                    $return[] = $key;
                }
            }
            elseif ($value === $needle) {
                if (is_integer($key)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $return[] = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    } elseif ($haystack === $needle) {
        return true;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the things I thought you did wrong was checking for if current $value is an array and doing a recursive search on it, while doing nothing with the return value of it (which should be the array either false ) , here I used a more step by step approach (well at least I thought so )
this works for a "tree with more branches"

**EDIT**

```
function recursive_search($needle, $haystack) {
        $values = array();
        foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
              $children = $this->recursive_search($needle, $value);
              if($children !== false){
                  if(!is_bool($children) and !empty($children)){
                    $key = array($key => $children);
                  }
                  $values[] = $key;
               } 
            } else if(strcmp($needle, $value) == 0 ){
                if(is_int($key))
                    return true;
                else
                    $vaues[] = $key;
             } 
    }
    if(!empty($values)) {
        return $values;
    }
    return false;
}
```

got rid of the "0"s in the array, thx Cheery for the hint (from his response)

Comment: An explanation would be great, it'd stop people from down-voting your answer and help the OP understand where he went wrong.

Comment: will edit in a minute with an update, and a better version, found a bug

Comment: Instead of `if($children != false){` use: `if(!is_bool($children)){`

Comment: @CharlesRojas this would be an option but the thing is the function can return a boolean(true) so it wouldn't pass there

Comment: Noticed if one of the top level keys is equal to the needle it will stop and return true

Comment: @ŢîganIon I thought that was the idea, in that case I was confused because of the Expected sample

Comment: I've modded it a bit to fix the top level entry, will edit your answer with it.

Comment: @Bankzilla added the top level fix :)

Comment: It makes the output return 0s everyone now, your edit overwrote mine a few second later haha

Comment: damn this var_Dump :)))

Comment: I tried somehow to go back and redo to your answer - but I don't know how :)